# Getting java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: You must be using an underlying instance of WebDriver that supports executing javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, selenide

We are running selenide java tests. They were doing fine few days back now they are failing with the error. Tests are only failing when any javascript action is done i.e executing some script or scrolling through the page.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: You must be using an underlying instance of WebDriver that supports executing javascript
```

Tests are triggered through jenkins on a remote VM.
Have added the
`--enable-javascript`.
Chrome version we have there is: 104 and selenide and testng versions are:

```
<selenide.version>6.10.0</selenide.version>
    <testng.version>7.6.1</testng.version>
```